# how is CTE giving output for the the below mentioned query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am very new in sql programming .i have 2 questions based on the below mentioned query

```
WITH CTE_Stars AS
(
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '*') Stars

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CTE_Stars.Stars+'*') Stars 
    FROM CTE_Stars  
    WHERE LEN(Stars) < 6
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE_Stars
```

Can someone explain how the above query is working and second this query does not work without convert function why..? Why do we need to convert '*' to character? By default `*` datatype is character only.

This query is giving output in 5 rows and that to without a loop.. how is this possible

Comment: Look up Recursive CTE on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Recursive CTE contains two definitions an Anchor member and Recursive member.
First it executes the anchor part once and recursive part once.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CTE_Stars.Stars+'*') Stars 
FROM CTE_Stars
```

As you are calling FROM `CTE_Stars`, In a recursive CTE, it executes only the Recursive members of CTE_Stars until it satisfies the where condition.
We need to use either `CAST` or `CONVERT` when we are using Characters where as when we are using integers it does not require any conversion function.